How do I spell out the month in a filename generated by sqlcmd?
I have a batch file that is using sqlcmd %date:~10,4%%date:~4,2% for a date stamp in a file name.  My client wants the month to be spelled out instead, so the date looks like blahblah_May2024.csv.
I tried %date_month%, didn't return anything.

sqlcmd isn't doing anything. The Windows command processor cmd.exe expands variables like %date% and it uses a format that varies depending on your region setting -- but I know of no region whose short date format goes out to 14 chars (or more); what part of the world are you, or if applicable your client, in? PowerShell supports deterministic and more flexible options. May is the shortest month name so I don't know if 'spelled out' means you want month 1 to be January or Jan; use get-date -format MMMMyyyy for the former and MMMyyyy for the latter.
